# what difference between use empty or not

Tags: php

```
$a = null;
$b = false;
$c = true;
$d = array();
$e = '';
$f;

//case 1
echo ($a)? '[true]<br>' : '[false]<br>';
echo ($b)? '[true]<br>' : '[false]<br>';
echo ($c)? '[true]<br>' : '[false]<br>';
echo ($d)? '[true]<br>' : '[false]<br>';
echo ($e)? '[true]<br>' : '[false]<br>';
echo ($f)? '[true]<br>' : '[false]<br>';

//case 2
echo !empty($a)? '[true]<br>' : '[false]<br>';
echo !empty($b)? '[true]<br>' : '[false]<br>';
echo !empty($c)? '[true]<br>' : '[false]<br>';
echo !empty($d)? '[true]<br>' : '[false]<br>';
echo !empty($e)? '[true]<br>' : '[false]<br>';
echo !empty($f)? '[true]<br>' : '[false]<br>';
```

--Output of the case 1--

```
[false]
[false]
[true]
[false]
[false]
Notice: Undefined variable: f in ... [false]
```

--Output of the case 2--

```
[false]
[false]
[true]
[false]
[false]
[false]
```

The result seems no difference between them, is it need to use empty()?

Guys THX.

I know the doc of PHP and difference with isset(), because I want to clean my code, the Notice is not occur a serious error, besides that I just want to get some advices.

Comment: try another test: say, `$g` without first initializing `$g`

Comment: Your output is wrong. $f is properly defined.

Answer (score 1):

`empty` would not raise an error if variable not defined. Also `empty` raise error (before php5.5) on expressions.

`Empty` equivalent to `!isset($var) || $var == false`. So `!empty` equivalent to `isset($var) && $var == true` or just `isset($var) && $var`. So `isset($var)` is the difference.

http://php.net/empty